# how to use eval in linux command if string conatins special character such as -

Tags: python, eval

I have tried this command

```
eval('my-value')
```

but this error

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'my' is not defined
```

but if i try

```
eval('myval')
```

i get this

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myval' is not defined
```

why did it is reading my and value differently in first command? how to tackle if a varible name conatins -

Comment: this looks like javascript, not a shell language

Comment: since this is javascript you are doing subtraction between the values `my` and `value`

Comment: no i am trying to exeute this command
python -c "import my_module; my_module.my_function(eval('var1'), eval('var2'))"
and the value of var1 is my-value @DanielA.White

Comment: The Linux tag should only be used for questions _specific to_ Linux, meaning problems you _couldn't_ cause outside Linux if you tried. Similarly, the command-line tag doesn't make sense here -- you'd have the same problem running the same code in a way that involved no command lines at all.

Comment: Clarify your question by [edit]ing it; things that are only in comments don't count as part of the question for purposes of being fair game to use in writing answers (so by a strict interpretation of the rules, @NapoleanDynamite shouldn't have edited to take your above comment into account until you updated your question to incorporate the content of that comment).

Comment: (It's also not clear what you mean by "variable name contains `-`" -- variable names _can't_ contain dashes in either python or POSIX-compliant shell languages

Comment: If you just want the string `'my-val'` transported from a shell variable into a Python variable, then why do you need `eval()` at all?

Comment: For example, watch this: `var1='my-val'; var1=$var1 python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["var1"])'` -- Python can print the variable with no `eval` needed anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDITED)
this clearly is not a linux command? It seems that you are in python environment rather than a shell.

If thats the case you should probably do something similar to this:

```
your_value = eval('myval')
```

OK, given your new context, you could try to use double quotes around the entire command and single quotes around the string arguments inside the eval, like:

```
python -c "import my_module; my_module.my_function(eval('\"$var1\"'), eval('\"$var2\"'))"
```

change var1 and var2 depending on your needs

Comment: no i am trying to exeute this command python -c "import my_module; my_module.my_function(eval('$var1'), eval('$var2'))" and the value of var1 is my-value 
and it shows 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'my' is not defined

Comment: i updated my answer:
`python -c "import my_module; my_module.my_function(eval('\"$var1\"'), eval('\"$var2\"'))"`
see if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding my context

Comment: Why would you do this over, say, `python -c "import my_module; my_module.my_function($var1, $var2)"`? (That's not good practice either -- _very_ far from it -- but you're not gaining anything by injecting content into a string _emdedded as a literal in your code_ that you then eval, vs injecting direct into your code).

Comment: The best idea would be not to use `eval` at all. Please read and understand: [eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: A slightly less-bad approach that still uses eval might be `var1=$var1 var2=$var2 python -c 'import my_module, os; my_module.my_function(eval(os.environ["var1"]), eval(os.environ["var2"]))'`, but _much_ better than that is not to use eval at all; for example, `ast.literal_eval()` is a far safer alternative that works as long as each variable holds one literal.

Comment: ...so, then, an example that uses neither eval nor any moral equivalent at all might be: `var1=$var1 var2=$var2 python -c 'import my_module, os, ast; my_module.my_function(ast.literal_eval(os.environ["var1"]), ast.literal_eval(os.environ["var2"]))'`

Comment: (mind, that's assuming that your variables hold Python literals; if they hold, say, JSON strings, then you should be using `json.loads()` instead of `ast.literal_eval()`)

Comment: Whereas if the OP just wants to store the exact/literal contents of a shell variable in a Python variable, why are you encouraging them to do anything that involves `eval` at all?